# Solving a differential equation with a a constraint equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have this second order differential equation that I need to solve given a constrain equation. Can I write both the equation and the constraint in mathetmaica? if so then how?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at, for example, `DSolve` and under Scope, see "Differential-algebraic equations".

Comment: Where is the equation?

Comment: @MapleSE-Area51Proposal Added a screen shot, the 1st equation is the constraint, the second one is the one that needs to be solved.

Comment: @MauricioLobos this can not be solved algebraically. numerically only and the constraint isn't just a simple y[0]=0 type to use that format.

Comment: Please add the equations in Mathematica format to the question, provide values for the constants, and describe what you have tried so far.